# Simple injector lifestyle warnings for web api controllers

Tags: c#, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm following the docs on the simple injector docs site.

https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html

```
var container = new Container();
container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config);
container.Verify();

var results = Analyzer.Analyze(container);

results.Should()
  .HaveCount(0, String.Join( Environment.NewLine, results.Select(x => x.Description)));
```

However when I run my test I get the following error

```
Xunit.Sdk.AssertException: 
Expected collection to contain 0 item(s) because 
MyController is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable., 
but found 1.
```

I'm not sure how to set the scope for controllers as the method `container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config)` is part of the webapi package and doesn't have any overloads.  How do I set these to per web request?  Elsewhere I would do this `container.Register<IPinger, Pinger>(lifestyle);` but it seems like I should be using the packaged helper method

---

Add this line in to filter out the unwanted false negatives

```
results = results.Where(x => 
   !(x.ServiceType.BaseType == typeof (ApiController) && 
     x.Description.Contains("IDisposable"))
    ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why are you writing tests to check DI configuration? It is virtually impossible to check whether a DI configuration is valid without running the application, in fact, the Verify method itself is not very useful: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/21/TestingContainerConfigurations/, even according to the documentation link you have provided.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe it should be removed from the docs then?

Comment: I disagree with NightOwl and the Mark's article. Although it might be impossible to get 100% certainty, verifying and diagnosing your container will however give you a good level of certainty, when you follow [certain rules](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration). Verifying and diagnosing your DI configuration is something that I view as almost a requirement when working with a team of developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Disposable Transient Components](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/disposabletransientcomponent.html) page contains more information about this warning and states:

> This warning can safely be ignored when: Dispose is called by the
>   application code

In the case of Web API, the Web API framework registers controllers for disposal, so this warning can safely be ignored for Web API controllers.

Although the lifestyle of Web API controllers can safely be increased to per-web-api-request, in general it is better to leave your root objects transient. Promoting the lifestyle will force you to promote the lifestyle of those dependencies as well, and will cause every registration in the application to be at least per-web-request. Although this can be done safely without any problem, this can make your registration a bit more complicated, and can have impact on the speed in which large object graphs are resolved.

So the warning is a false-positive in your case. It can safely be ignored. It would be good if the integration libraries suppress these warnings. I just created a [work item for this](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/workitem/21006). Expect it to be fixed in a future release.

You can use the following code to suppress these warnings:

```
var results = 
    from result in Analyzer.Analyze(container)
    let disposableController =
        result is DisposableTransientComponentDiagnosticResult &&
        typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(result.ServiceType)
    where !disposableController
    select result;

results.Should().HaveCount(0, String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    results.Select(x => x.Description)));
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer!  I'll filter out the warnings for controllers. Great library by the way and the in depth docs help a lot!

Comment: @Niel: See my update to see how to suppress these warnings. You can filter on the `DisposableTransientComponentDiagnosticResult`.

Comment: @Neil: We just pushed [a beta of v2.8 to NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector/2.8.0-beta1) that suppresses this warning on Web API controllers. I'm really interested to hear how this beta works out for you.

Comment: @Steven, I just upgraded to 3.0.5, so I suppose this issue was never addressed?

Comment: @Rogier21: it has been addressed. Your issue is probably different.  Best is to start a new question on SO or on Github.

Comment: @Rogier21 I was getting the same error, but on version 3.0.3. After making sure all the Simple Injector packages were updated to 3.0.5, I performed a Clean Project, then Rebuild Project. Problem seems to have gone away, so perhaps it's simply that the binaries in your \bin folder haven't been updated?